# Why won't IE7 recognize class calls to an external stylesheet, but will recognize inline styling?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, ie-developer-tools

When using IE8 to view IE7 through the developer tool's browser mode feature, I am having an odd recurring problem with CSS.  When I make changes to an external stylesheet and then reference that class in the HTML, it's like IE7 won't recognize it at all.  If, however, I put that same styling inline, IE7 will obey it.  Has anyone heard of this before?  Here's a simple example to help illustrate what I'm saying:

External stylesheet:

```
.bold {
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

Call in HTML:

```
<p class="bold">My paragraph here</p>
```

No changes will be effective in IE7, although all other browsers are fine.

If however, I do this:

```
<p style="font-weight:bold;">My paragraph here</p>
```

IE7 seems happy.  What's the difference? Do I really have to make CSS changes this way, or is there another workaround?

I'm baffled as to what the issue could be.  I don't know if the developer tool's browser mode has a quirk and doesn't quite work as a real-life version of IE7 would, or if this is something completely different.  I am using IE8 (I can't upgrade to IE9 at this government computer), but I've heard the problem persists with my changes in IE9's browser mode of IE7 too.

We're using ColdFusion to generate the HTML, using an HTML5 doctype (), and I've added a timestamp parameter to the 2 external stylesheet references so the browser is forced to grab a new copy every time.

Any help with this mystery would be hugely appreciated - thank you!

======
For @Stano or anyone else who is interested in recreating the exact problem, here is a stripped down version of it: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B02DZPpIlMwGSk1VZHRDUHNCTkU (Can click File > Download to get the zip).  Notice in IE7, "Photographer" is fine because it has inline styling, but the others aren't picking up anything.

Comment: Any chance you've got more than 31 stylesheets linked to in the head?  IE will ignore any sheets after that number and you'll pull your hair out trying to figure out why your styles are being ignored.

Comment: Try it on IETester IE7. IE8 in IE7 mode is not equal to IE7.

Comment: Could it be cached? Have you tried clear browser cache and try again?

Comment: Is it all styles that are ignored, or only specific ones? And does it work without the "timestamp parameter"? And what if you put the styles in a `<style>` block in the HTML's head?

Comment: Are you using any type of CSS reset or IE conditional comments? Maybe something is overwriting it somewhere.

Comment: @JGrubb nope - just 3 external stylesheets

Comment: @Rustam thanks - I've heard of this tool but need to be really convinced that's the problem first, because I have to fill out forms and go through a bunch of red tape to get it installed on a government computer.  I'd love to try it out though!  It may come to this.

Comment: @Trekstuff the parameter in the reference *should* fix that issue (http://css-tricks.com/can-we-prevent-css-caching/), but I do have my IE8 settings to "Check for newer version of stored pages every time I visit the webpage."

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck that's a good idea - I am using Blueprint's (http://blueprintcss.org/) reset and conditional [if lt IE8]...I'll comment those out and let you know what happens.

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck it seems commenting those 2 references out make no difference.  I did get some success by referencing a new stylesheet that only had my new class in it.  IE7 likes that for some reason...maybe there is some sort of caching going on with developer tool's mode.

Comment: @Stano - IE7 will obey most class calls, especially if it's the first time ever loading the page.  If you add a change to ietest.css now and refresh it, will IE7 accept your change?

Comment: @user1411056 Yes, on localhost it worked ok. You can test it too, here are both files (html+css) ziped: http://www.ulozto.net/xSJZ6dE/ietest-zip

Comment: @Stano - thanks, you're right.  That looks good in IE7 mode from IE8.  Even adding another class to your css file took effect.  Maybe some other CSS is interacting to cause this headache.

Comment: @Stano Interestingly, when viewing your example page with IE developer tools you can click on the p element on the page and on the right side of the developer tools window on the "Style" tab, your class comes right up.  The same cannot be said for my page.  The class does not show up on in the Style tab at all.

Comment: @user1411056 Ok, then you have some another complication. I am sorry don't know how to solve your problem. I think some of Zachary's tips can solve the issue. Good luck!

Comment: @Stano edit up above with link if you're still interested.  I'm sure it's hard when my description didn't make it so you could recreate the problem - sorry about that!

Comment: You're right, it's not bold in IE7.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your comments, you're right in saying that it could be a caching issue, but it could also be an issue with that stylesheet (though it doesn't look like that's the case), another stylesheet, or invalid HTML.

One of the things that I want to correct you on, because I think it may influence your understanding of how CSS and HTML interact, is that `class` attributes in HTML elements do not *call* CSS. Rather, CSS rules tell the browser agent how to render things with certain attributes. This is why we are able to use the elements ID, name, groupname, class, and other values to identify which elements to apply which class to.

I mention this because if you have invalid HTML (a missing end tag, a missing arrow, etc.) it can do all sorts of weird things. A few days ago it helped me solve an issue where a misplaced tag was actually causing a script of mine to loop on one of my pages.

Take a quick second and validate your HTML using the [W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.  I cannot seem to get the page to validate.  The validator didn't like 3 meta tags, so I removed them, but they keep coming up as errors in the validator even though they don't exist on the page anymore.  I'm not having the best luck today!  Even though I removed those lines, IE7 looks the same.

Comment: give the validator a few minutes and then run it again. It may cache (lol cache is a real pain today for everyone it seems)

Comment: I finally got it to validate, but it this didn't fix the problem.  Of course it still seems like a good idea to validate anyway.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah, sorry that didn't do it.